# How to check if an entire column is sparse in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

How do I check if an entire column is sparse? I know the hack way to do this would be replace all "0" entries with NA and then then check with is.na:

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
sapply(df, function(x)all(is.na(x)))
```

Is there a quicker way to do this where I don't have to go through the entire matrix and replace all empty values with NA?

Comment: Not sure if I got this correctly. Wouldn't `apply(df, 2, function(x) all(x == 0))` be enough?

Comment: @Molx `apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(x) == 0)` might actually be faster. I tested `sum(x) == 0` against `all(x == 0)` with `microbenchmark` for `x <-  rep(0, 100000)` and the `sum` version was about 3x faster than the `all` version. Still, you definitely don't need to convert to `NA` here.

Comment: @ssdecontrol - with no information about the values in the matrix it's possible that "non-empty" columns may sum to zero. using `all` is safer.

Comment: @Jay I didn't even think of that; somehow I was imagining only positive numbers. It also might be slower if decimals are involved

Comment: @ssdecontrol I actually comented that first, but then realized the same as @Jay did. Since we have no idea of what the data is there's a chance positive and negative numbers would cancel each others into `sum = 0`.

Comment: @Jay sorry I didn't clarify but all the values are positive. So checking     which(colSums(df)==0) does the trick!

Comment: When you don't know anything about the data, you could also do `length(unique(mycol))==1`

Answer (score 0):

#### Summarizing from the comments

Converting to `NA` is completely unnecessary here. You could just directly check that

```
sapply(df, function(x) all(x == 0))
```

Depending on your data, you have two other alternatives:

- For nonnegative numeric data, `colSums(x) == 0`
- `sapply(df, function(x) x[1] == 0 && length(unique(x)) == 1)`

#### Benchmarks

Specs:

- MacBook Pro Retina, late 2013, 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Mac OS 10.10.5
- R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14), installed as a bundled application from CRAN.

Code:

```
library(microbenchmark)

ncol <- 1000L
nrow <- 10000L
dense_frac <- 1/3
n_dense <- dense_frac %/% ncol
x <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow, ncol))
dense_cols <- sample(ncol, n_dense)

all_zero <- function(x) {
  all(x == 0)
}

first_zero_all_same <- function(x) {
  x[1] == 0 && length(unique(x)) == 1L
}

zero_to_na <- function(x) {
  x[x == 0] <- NA
  all(is.na(x))
}

bench <- function(x) microbenchmark(
  colsum.zero = colSums(x) == 0,
  raw.colsum.zero = .colSums(as.matrix(x), nrow, ncol) == 0,
  apply.all.zero = apply(x, 2, all_zero),
  sapply.all.zero = sapply(x, all_zero),
  apply.first.zero.all.same = apply(x, 2, first_zero_all_same),
  sapply.first.zero.all.same = sapply(x, first_zero_all_same),
  apply.convert.to.na = apply(x, 2, zero_to_na),
  sapply.convert.to.na = sapply(x, zero_to_na),
  times = 10,
  control = list(order = "block")
)

set.seed(43770)
gc()

## non-negative integers
x[dense_cols] <- replicate(n_dense, rpois(nrow))
nneg_int <- bench(x)

## non-negative decimals
x[dense_cols] <- replicate(n_dense, abs(rnorm(nrow)))
nneg_dec <- bench(x)
```

Results:

```
print(nneg_int)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                        expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval    cld
#                 colsum.zero  46.1  46.9  54.1   52.4  63.4  65.8    10 a     
#             raw.colsum.zero  46.6  48.3  59.5   53.8  57.2 120.7    10 a     
#              apply.all.zero 247.8 301.3 301.3  306.5 309.9 316.0    10    d  
#             sapply.all.zero  39.9  43.3  45.3   45.5  46.5  51.0    10 a     
#   apply.first.zero.all.same 494.0 494.5 509.5  515.6 518.0 526.2    10      f
#  sapply.first.zero.all.same 236.5 244.4 250.9  250.0 256.9 261.9    10   c   
#         apply.convert.to.na 436.1 479.8 481.6  486.7 492.2 498.0    10     e 
#        sapply.convert.to.na 220.6 226.6 230.6  229.6 234.3 239.7    10  b    

print(nneg_dec)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                        expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval   cld
#                 colsum.zero  45.0  47.4  58.3   52.2  60.6 108.2    10 a    
#             raw.colsum.zero  45.2  53.8  55.0   54.7  58.6  65.7    10 a    
#              apply.all.zero 297.9 304.0 318.8  314.7 323.3 367.5    10   c  
#             sapply.all.zero  40.0  44.0  46.5   44.4  46.8  59.1    10 a    
#   apply.first.zero.all.same 502.9 534.4 536.2  539.8 543.5 547.6    10     e
#  sapply.first.zero.all.same 240.0 243.5 250.9  249.7 258.1 264.0    10  b   
#         apply.convert.to.na 492.5 493.1 498.7  498.2 499.4 518.0    10    d 
#        sapply.convert.to.na 228.8 236.0 240.4  238.4 244.1 253.8    10  b
```

On this sample data, it looks like the best option is in fact using `sapply` to check that `all(x == 0)`, while the `colSums` approach is second-best.